# How to only have 1 project run with Tomcat Server (Eclipse)?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

Is there a way in Eclipse to only have one project be run on the specified Tomcat server, even if there are multiple projects in the workspace?

Comment: Are the other projects independant of the Tomcat related project? Essentially, you can create any number of C, C++, Python, Dynamic Web (e.g. to run it on Tomcat or another app server), Java etc. applications inside a workspace. The execution environment (like app server) can be specified on a per-project basis. Not sure if this is your question, though ...

Comment: All of the projects use the same Tomcat server (aka they are all Tomcat projects), but what I want to know is if I can have some projects run when I start up the server and have some not run.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, right click on your server and select `Add and remove projects`.

You can find more information [here](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.wst.server.ui.doc.user/topics/twaddprj.html).